# distance measurement using disparity map

Tags: python, opencv

I was working on 3D reconstruction and distance measurement using OpenCP and Python. I generate the disparity map for the left camera and then I used this formula to get the distance:

```
D=(f*b/disp)
```

Where `f` is the focal length, `b` is the distance between the 2 cameras and `disp` is the matrix of the disparity map.

My questions are:

The numbers that I get, are they supposed to be the distance of each point in the picture?

What is the max distance that I can get with this method (for example in my project the max      number i get is 110)?

```
img_L = cv2.pyrDown( cv2.imread(Li) )
img_R = cv2.pyrDown( cv2.imread(Ri) )
'''h, w = img_L.shape[:2]
diff=(6,6,6)
mask=np.zeros((h+2,w+2),np.uint8)
window_size = 3
min_disp = 16
num_disp = 112-min_disp
stereo = cv2.StereoSGBM(minDisparity = min_disp,
    numDisparities = num_disp,
    SADWindowSize = window_size,
    uniquenessRatio = 10,
    speckleWindowSize = 100,
    speckleRange = 32,
    disp12MaxDiff = 1,
    P1 = 8*3*window_size**2,
    P2 = 32*3*window_size**2,
    fullDP = False
)
print "computing disparity..."
disp = stereo.compute(img_L, img_R).astype(np.float32) / 16.0

print "generating 3d point cloud..."
h, w = img_L.shape[:2]
f = 0.8*w                          # guess for focal length
points = cv2.reprojectImageTo3D(disp, Mat)
colors = cv2.cvtColor(img_L, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
mask = disp > disp.min()
cv2.imshow('left', img_L)
disparity=(disp-min_disp)/num_disp
cv2.imshow('disparity',disparity )
b=6.50
D=b*f/disp
cv2.waitKey()
cv.DestroyAllWindows()
return D
```

Answer (score 5):

The values `D` that you get using this formula are the *depths* of each point for which you provided a disparity.

The *depth* and the *distance* are two slightly different things. If you use the standard coordinate system for a camera (i.e. Z axis along the optical axis, X and Y axis in the directions of the image X and Y axis), then a 3D point `M = (X, Y, Z)` has a distance of `sqrt(X²+Y²+Z²)` from the optical center and a depth of `Z`. The `D` in the formula is the depth, not the distance.

If you want to retrieve the 3D point `M = (X, Y, Z)` from the depth value, you need to know the camera matrix `K`: `M = D * inv(K) * [u; v; 1]`, where `(u, v)` are the image coordinates of the point.

**Edit:** Concerning your second question, the maximum depth that you can get with this method is linked to the minimum disparity (not the maximum, since `disp` is on the denominator). And since disparity estimation is quantified (done pixel by pixel), you can't estimate depth up to infinity.

Comment: @ AldurDisciple howcome?!!! cause according to this page http://disparity.wikidot.com/ D is the distance
and if it is as you said, which camera matrix should i use (cause i'm using two cameras for the stereovision), how can i get the image coordinates of the point?

Comment: @user3433195 they call it "distance" but it's really the depth. Also, why don't you use `reprojectImageTo3D` ([link](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#reprojectimageto3d)) ?

Comment: @ AlderDisciple i did use it ,i added the code above

Comment: I am also trying to calculate actual distance from depth map. Wanted to check how to get Mat. Why you have multiplied focal length by width ? And how to get camera matrix K: M = D * inv(K) * [u; v; 1] as mentioned above to calculate actual distance